# AJAX login redirecting to returned URL (security)

Tags: ajax, security

I'm working on AJAX login form. On submit it sends login data to back-end. If there is a problem with login, appropriate response is returned. When login data valid, back-end creates a session for user and sends back a URL where user should be redirected. I want to return URL, because it changes depending on multiple user settings (language, personal/business, etc.).

Am I overlooking any security issues with this approach? Is it possible for attacker to redirect user to malicious website when browser trusts URL returned from AJAX call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's a pretty standard method for handling login via an asynchronous handler (assuming that you're doing this over HTTPS, if not, all bets are off).

And yes, it is possible for an attacker to redirect a user, if you allow the attacker to set where the redirect goes.

So that means that you should validate any user-inputted (and hence potentially attacker set) URLs that you're going to redirect to make sure they are safe. Basically make sure the URL is on your domain, and make sure that it's a valid URL. You can go deeper (check for XSS style attacks, etc), but you usually shouldn't have to as long as you're practicing good security practices in the rest of the application.

But then again, that's just basic application security *Filter-In, Escape-Out*. So filter the inputted URL, and you should be fine...

Comment: All this, plus HTTPS for added safety